# ELKI cluster extraction HiSC HiCO

Tags: cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, elki

I'm comuputing HiCO and HiSC clustering algorithms on my dataset. If I'm not mistaken, the algorithms use different approach to define relevant subspaces for clusters in the 1st step and in the 2nd they apply OPTICS for clustering. I'm getting only cluster order file after I run the algorithms. 
Is there any way to extract clusters from it? for example like OPTICSXi? (I know there are 3 extraction methods under hierarchical clustering but I can't see anything for HiCO or HiSC)
Thank you in advance for any hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OPTICSXi as algorithm, then use HiCO or HiSC "inside".

The Xi extraction can be parameterized to use a different OPTICS variant like HiCO, HiSC, and DeLi-Clu. It just defaults to using regular OPTICS.

```
-algorithm clustering.optics.OPTICSXi
-opticsxi.algorithm de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.algorithm.clustering.correlation.HiCO
```

respectively

```
-algorithm clustering.optics.OPTICSXi
-opticsxi.algorithm de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.algorithm.clustering.subspace.HiSC
```

We currently don't have implementations of the other extraction methods in ELKI yet, sorry.